# Defining an array of only one object in YAML

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yaml

I'm trying to use [load-grunt-config](https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config) to organise better my Grunt tasks.

So far I have had no issues with this. Now, I was trying to configure something like [imagemin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin).

So, basically this is the structure I'm trying to replicate within YAML:

```
dynamic: {                         // Another target
  files: [{
    expand: true,                  // Enable dynamic expansion
    cwd: 'src/',                   // Src matches are relative to this path
    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],   // Actual patterns to match
    dest: 'dist/'                  // Destination path prefix
  }]
}
```

And this is my attempt:

```
images:
  files: [
    expand: true
    cwd: '<%= ui %>/img/'
    src:
      - '**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'
    dest: '<%= dist %>/img'
  ]
```

However, something must be wrong as the plugin isn't able to get the correct data and hence, fails.

```
>> JS-YAML: missed comma between flow collection entries in "grunt/imagemin.yaml" at line 4, column 8:
>>         cwd: '<%= ui %>/img/'
>>
```

Does anyone knows what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets are only for in-line lists. Your list of files should look like this:

```
images:
  files: 
    - expand: true
      cwd: '<%= ui %>/img/'
      src:
        - '**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'
      dest: '<%= dist %>/img'
```

You can test your YAML for correct syntax with an online parser like [this](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) one.

Comment: Thanks! This syntax is totally new to me